Customization on carbon portal WSO2 API Manager 4.2
Can we customize the carbon portal to add a response header like “x-frame-options:deny” and few more headers?
if we can where can I edit the contents header for this? or there’s any policy that state we can’t change the carbon portal details? Thank you

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Are there any specific reason to use the Carbon Portal and set a response header for the Carbon portal? Do you need the mentioned response header appended in the response when trying to access the Carbon portal from the browser? Or are you trying to invoke any legacy endpoints that are exposed via Carbon Portal to fulfil any requirements?
Carbon portal is a legacy application, and most of the API Management configurations and deployment are handled through Publisher and Devportal. Therefore, it is better to keep restricted access to the Carbon portal unless there is a necessity.
